# What does the type graph look like in Julia?

Tags: types, julia, dispatch

I just started looking a Julia. I'm interested in how it accomplishes multiple dispatch, specifically how it determines the type for use in multiple dispatch.

In the introduction to [Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/),the [manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/getting-started/) states:

> all values in Julia are true objects having a type that belongs to a single, fully connected type graph, all nodes of which are equally first-class as types

**My question is**: How is the type graph connected?

For example, where would an `Array` of `Integer`s fit in? Is it a subtype of `Array` or a subtype of `Integer`? Both?

How 'bout `Complex` numbers? Can I have `Array`s (2x1) of `Rational` and `Duples` (2-Tuples) of `Integers` *both* be `Complex`?

```
# This is my first Julia code ever. It is probably wrong.
abstract type Rational <: Number end
abstract type Integer <: Rational end
abstract type Complex <: Array{Integer, 2} end
abstract type Complex <: Tuple{Rational, Rational} end
(1, 2)::Complex * (1, 2)::Complex
```

In the above two examples, I'm using `"code font"` to denote abstract types.

Maybe the code example is the "wrong" concept? Maybe I should define a "multiply complex" function in stead?

Can you show me a drawing of the type graph for the built-in types?

Comment: [It's complicated](http://janvitek.org/pubs/oopsla18a.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, @phipsgabler. For other readers of this article, the abstract of [the complicated article](http://janvitek.org/pubs/oopsla18a.pdf) states "This paper provides the first formal definition of Julia’s subtype relation and motivates its design."

Answer (score 3):

Here is the number type tree taken from https://github.com/bkamins/The-Julia-Express
This link also makes a good first reading.

[image]

In the type hierarchy you can see:

- abstract types - these are to define the overall type structure. In Julia you can inherit only from an abstract type. Hence all branching types in this tree are abstract
- concrete types - these are all the leaves
- parametric types. These are the values that come after `{}`. `T <: Integer` means that any parametric type being a subtype of `Integer` will be accepted as a parametric type. Parametric types allow you to have things like `Complex{Float64}` and `Complex{Int}` - that is complex numbers defined over various type spaces. With Julia's multiple dispatch magic things like this "just work".

Hope this helps for the beginning. Another useful free resource is https://juliaacademy.com/